# Call another class and getText

Tags: android

```
public class ustawienia extends MainActivity {
    EditText kryptonim;
    public String test;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ustawienia);
        kryptonim  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_kryptonim);
        test = kryptonim.getText().toString();
}

    public String call_back(){
        return test;
    }
}
```

When call call_back() from another class I've got error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. What's wrong with that?

Comment: where are you calling add code

Comment: I call my code in MainActivity:   
  public void download_test(){
        ustawienia ustawienia_okno = new ustawienia();
        String a = ustawienia_okno.call_back();
        Log.i("##### The text is: ", a);
    }

Answer (score 0):

When you close an activity all data from it is lost, so unless both activities are runing at the same time you can't retrieve data. You could use shared prefrences instead.
// IN ORDER TO WRITE TO A FILE

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = getSharedPreferences("PrefsName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 
 prefs.putString("test", kryptonim.getText().toString());
 prefs.apply(); // use prefs.commit(); if this doesn't work
```

In order to read data

```
SharedPreferences prefsR = getSharedPreferences("PrefsName", MODE_PRIVATE); // you could also write 0 instead MODE_PRIVATE
String restoredText = prefsR.getString("test", null);
```

Ofcourse you need to import SharedPrefs , and put this in oncreate or wherever you want... let me now if it works :)